# Recursive selection in C++ not fully working

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, selection-sort

I'm trying to write a recursive function that sorts a small array by selection. I can get everything to load and run, but the output when the array is `{3, 1, 8, 5}` keeps outputting as `{1, 3, 3, 3}`. I think it's got something to do with how the minimum value is assigned, but I'm stuck on exactly where that is. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int arrLength = 4;
int minimum;
int counter = 0;

int sortedArr[];
int tempArr[];

void sortFunc(int, int);

int valueArr[4] = { 3,1,8,5 };
int tempArr[4] = {};

void main() {

    cout << "Before sorting..." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << valueArr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    sortFunc(4, counter);

    cout << "After sorting..." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //either broken here
        cout << tempArr[i] << " ";
    }

    _getch();
}

void sortFunc(int size, int counter) {
    minimum = valueArr[0];

    for (int i = 1 + (counter); i <  size; i++) { //or here
        if (valueArr[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = valueArr[i];
        }
    }

    tempArr[counter] = minimum;

    if (counter < size) {
        counter++;
        sortFunc(size, counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger before, this is the perfect time to learn it. Using a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for any programmer.

Comment: Oh and you have *some* checks for `counter` not being out of bounds, but not where it's really needed so you *will* go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. If you used a debugger this would have been very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't clearly see how your strategy can be tweaked just a bit to make your function work. I think you need to sort the array in place by swapping elements. For that to work, you need to:

1. Copy `valueArr` to `tempArr` first.
2. Sort `tempArr` in place. That leaves `valueArr` in its original state. I am assuming that was your intention.

In `main`, use:

```
// Copy valueArr to tempArr
std::copy(valueArr, valueArr+4, tempArr);
```

In `sortFunc`, use:

```
void sortFunc(int size, int counter) {
   if ( size == counter )
   {
      return;
   }

    int minimum = tempArr[counter];

    for (int i = 1 + (counter); i <  size; i++) {
        if (tempArr[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = tempArr[i];
            std::swap(tempArr[counter], tempArr[i]); 
        }
    }

    sortFunc(size, counter+1);
}
```

---

Suggestions for further cleanup.

1. Don't use any global variables.
2. Pass all the arguments to `sortFunc`.
3. Change the return type of `main` to `int`.

Here's a cleaned up version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void sortFunc(int arr[], int, int);

int main() {

    cout << "Before sorting..." << endl;

    int valueArr[4] = { 3,1,8,5 };
    int tempArr[4] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << valueArr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Copy valueArr to tempArr
    std::copy(valueArr, valueArr+4, tempArr);
    sortFunc(tempArr, 4, 0);

    cout << "After sorting..." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //either broken here
        cout << tempArr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void sortFunc(int arr[], int size, int counter) {
   if ( size == counter )
   {
      return;
   }

    int minimum = arr[counter];

    for (int i = 1 + (counter); i <  size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = arr[i];
            std::swap(arr[counter], arr[i]); 
        }
    }

    sortFunc(arr, size, counter+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should not be initializing the minimum value at line

`minimum = valueArr[0];`

Instead just assign it to large number or use `valueArr[counter + 1]`

The reason for this strange behavior is likely that the first entry in valueArr is actually smaller than those you encounter later in the array, therefore it won't get properly initialized...

ADD: See [INT_MAX](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) or [numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/) for the "large number"

---

ADD2: Anyway, looking more closely, your recursion has incorrect concept... if you intend to sort the array, you have to always swap the current element with the one you choose in every iteration. Otherwise you will start loosing elements, as you do. In any case, recursion might not be the best way to tackle sorting... Maybe try two nested cycles

Answer (score 0):

There were some basic logical errors in your code,

```
void sortFunc(int size, int counter) {
    minimum = 2147483647; // Point 1
    int mytemp;
    for (int i = 0; i <  size; i++) { // Point 3
        if (valueArr[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = valueArr[i];  //Point 2
            mytemp = i;
        }
    }
    valueArr[mytemp] = 2147483647;
    tempArr[counter] = minimum;

    if (counter < size) {
        counter++;
        sortFunc(size, counter);
    }
}
```

1. The `minimum` variable should always be the maximum possible value and you need to keep track of the index of the min value in the `valueArr`

2. After finding out a minumum value in `valueArr`, you need to make sure you don't visit the same value again, so keep track of it's index and change it's value necessarily
3. The loop iterable starts from `1+(counter)` in your code, what if the minimum lies before that? That's why you need to start from the beginning.

I hope you got my point. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the useful advice and tips provided in [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153581/8012646), the following function template would work as a recursive *STL-like* implementation of the *selection sort* algorithm:

```
#include <iterator>   // std::next
#include <algorithm>  // std::min_element

template<typename ForwardIt>
void sortFunc(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    // base case
    if (first == last || std::next(first) == last)
        return; // empty range or range with a single element

    // recursive case
    auto selected_it = std::min_element(first, last);
    using std::swap;
    swap(*selected_it, *first);
    return selection_sort(++first, last);
}
```

This way selection sort can be performed on any type that implements `operator<`, and it is not limited to just `int` (as in your `sortFunc()`).

The implementation above allows for [tail recursion optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to take place, so, don't forget to enable it, if you are going to sort large arrays (or other collections).

---

You can use the `sortFunc` function template above with C-style arrays (as in your example):

```
// copy valueArr to tempArr
std::copy(valueArr, valueArr+4, tempArr);
// sort tempArr
sortFunc(tempArr, tempArr+4);
```

as well as with any STL container that implements forward iterators:

```
std::vector<int> vec(valueArr, valueArr+4);
std::list<int> lst(valueArr, valueArr+4);
std::forward_list<int> fwdlst(valueArr, valueArr+4);

sortFunc(vec.begin(), vec.end());
sortFunc(lst.begin(), lst.end());
sortFunc(fwdlst.begin(), fwdlst.end());
```